# $\sinh(x) - \sin(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x \ge 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How can I show that $\sinh(x) - \sin(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x \ge 0, x \in \mathbb{R}? $ I couldn't find anything on search.

I have tried following: Let $f(x) = \sinh(x) - \sin(x)$. Now we know that $\sinh(x) = (e^x - e^{-x})/2$ so $f(x) = (e^x - e^{-x})/2 - \sin(x) $.

Differentiating that we get $f'(x) = (e^x + e^{-x})/2 - \cos(x).$ I'm having trouble showing that $ f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0.$

If we could do that we can argue that the derivative is positive so $f$ is increasing and $f(0) = 0$, therefore $f(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x \ge 0$.

We haven't covered any series stuff yet.

Comment: You can deduce from the taylor expansion of $\sinh$ that $\sinh x \geq x$ for $x \geq 0$ whereas we already know that $\sin x \leq x$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but we haven't covered any series or taylor expansions yet as stated in the question. I'm looking for more elementary aproach. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2-1=\frac{(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2}2\ge0
$$ then one may recall that $\cos x \le1$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

$$f(0)=\sinh(0)-\sin(0)=0 \quad (1)$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}-\cos x)$$

Using $AM-GM$ inequality we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})\geq\sqrt{e^x\cdot e^{-x}}=1$$

But we also know that $\cos x \leq 1$ and then $f'(x) \geq 0 \quad (2)$, so putting together $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude that $f(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor series

$$f(x)=\sinh(x)-\sin (x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
we see easily that $f(x)\ge0$ for $x\ge0$.